# XSLT append URL from relative to absolute

Tags: url, xslt, absolute-path, relative-url

In my XML document, I am pulling the content of a `<TextBlock>` that contains images. The XML shows:

```
<img src="/templates_soft/images/facebook.png" alt="twitter" />
```

When I view the page, the image doesn't show up because it is not at the same path as the original page.

I need to add the rest of the URL for the images to display. Something like `http://www.mypage.com/` so that the image displays from `http://www.mypage.com/templates_soft/images/facebook.png`

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and short XSLT solution. :)

Comment: Besides @Dimitre's good answer, there are cases for wich [@xml:base](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlbase/) is the right choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use**:

```
<img src="{$imageBase/}templates_soft/images/facebook.png" alt="twitter" />
```

where the xsl:variable named `$imageBase` is defined to contain the necessary prefix (in your case `"http://www.mypage.com"`).

**Here is a complete XSLT solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:param name="pimageBase" select="'http://www.mypage.com'"/>

    <xsl:template match="img">
   <img src="{concat($pimageBase, @src)}" alt="{@alt}"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<img src="/templates_soft/images/facebook.png" alt="twitter" />
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<img src="http://www.mypage.com/templates_soft/images/facebook.png" alt="twitter"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you go with XSLT, you simply create an XML that contains the entire URL as you desire, you then tag the XSLT up so it contains the "pointers" to the original fields in the XML file. If you are binding to a control, like a Grid, you can row bind and add the information at that point, if it is easier for you to do than XSLT.